# RxJs: Is it correct to use try/catch into subscribe()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, publish-subscribe

Let's assume that we have angular 2 application. Some service method return data via post(), where we have catch() to catch possible errors.

In component we have subscribed on the Observable's data:

```
  .subscribe(
              ()=> {
                      // some code
                   } 
             )
```

let's assume that I try to get some data from locaStorage or any another critical operation. Can I add try/catch statement inside such method ? Or is there another correct approach ?

Comment: If operations can be a moved from `subscribe` to observable operators, this will naturally provide error handling. This really depends on what exactly you do there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`subscribe` does give you options to pass in `onNext` and `onError`, but using `subscribe` for all side-effects isn't the best option. The whole point of Rx is to provide operators (such as `catch`, `retry` etc) to handle situations in a reactive fashion, and not simply use subscribe as a way to invoke callbacks.